# How to generate a Gaussian random velocity field

Tags: random, vector, correlation

Let us assume we have a 2-dimensional velocity field $\textbf{u}=(u_x,u_y)$ defined via its stream function $\psi(\textbf{x})$ as

\begin{cases}
u_x=\partial_y\psi(\textbf{x}) \\
u_y=-\partial_x\psi(\textbf{x}) \ .
\end{cases}

I want now to generate such a velocity field in a squared domain with the stream function $\psi(\textbf{x})$ being with zero mean and correlation function given by

$$\langle \psi(\textbf{x})\psi(\textbf{x}')\rangle = \sigma^2 \exp\biggr[-\frac{|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}'|^2}{2l^2}\biggr] \ .$$

Is it possible to do so in Mathematica? How shall I proceed? Thanks in advance for your help.